# How do I rewrite with callbacks to remove the need for separate variable labels?

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

I have a hit and miss (luck) success rate with JS callbacks. Sometimes I can for weeks put together quite complicated objects and controls and then **BHAM** one eye is twitching and I'm pressing buttons with my best chimp impression. Those with the knowledge will point out the obvious that I never knew so I've so far been a perfect example of the [Dunning–Kruger effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect)

I learn much better by example so in the code under **Faulty Approach** all the values take on the last value assigned and you end up in *twitch* mode. The second snippet **Naive Approach** assigned different labels to avoid the first snippets problem.

In the first snippet the first 3x lines fetch values and asign them to an element.

```
        var x = $(".slider-x").slider("value"),
            y = $(".slider-y").slider("value");
        $('.svg-position').attr("transform", "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")");
```

Without callbacks, the values assigned are overwritten by later lines.

**How do I rewrite with callbacks to remove the need for separate variable labels?**

**Faulty Approach**

```
    $('.svg-icon').click(function () {

        var x = $(".slider-x").slider("value"),
            y = $(".slider-y").slider("value");
        $('.svg-position').attr("transform", "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")");
        var scale = $(".slider-svglogo-scale").slider("value");
        $('.svg-size').attr("transform", "scale(" + scale / 100 + ")");                
        var scale = $(".slider-title-text-scale").slider("value");
        $('.svg-business-title').css("font-size", scale1 + "px");            
        var x = $(".slider-title-text-x").slider("value"),
            y = $(".slider-title-text-y").slider("value");
        $('.title-text').attr("x", x);
        $('.title-text').attr("y", y);
        var strap = $('.text-strap').val();
        $('.svg-strap-line').text(strap);
        var x = $(".slider-strapline-text-x").slider("value"),
            y = $(".slider-strapline-text-y").slider("value");
        $('.strapline-text').attr("x", x);
        $('.strapline-text').attr("y", y);
        var scale = $(".slider-strapline-text-scale").slider("value");
        $('.svg-strap-line').css("font-size", scale + "px"); 

        //some code that builds html and sets values
    });
```

**Naive Approach**

```
    $('.svg-icon').click(function () {

        var x = $(".slider-x").slider("value"),
            y = $(".slider-y").slider("value");
        $('.svg-position').attr("transform", "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")");
        var scale = $(".slider-svglogo-scale").slider("value");
        $('.svg-size').attr("transform", "scale(" + scale / 100 + ")");                
        var scale1 = $(".slider-title-text-scale").slider("value");
        $('.svg-business-title').css("font-size", scale1 + "px");            
        var x1 = $(".slider-title-text-x").slider("value"),
            y1 = $(".slider-title-text-y").slider("value");
        $('.title-text').attr("x", x1);
        $('.title-text').attr("y", y1);
        var strap = $('.text-strap').val();
        $('.svg-strap-line').text(strap);
        var x2 = $(".slider-strapline-text-x").slider("value"),
            y2 = $(".slider-strapline-text-y").slider("value");
        $('.strapline-text').attr("x", x2);
        $('.strapline-text').attr("y", y2);
        var scale2 = $(".slider-strapline-text-scale").slider("value");
        $('.svg-strap-line').css("font-size", scale2 + "px"); 

        //some code that builds html and sets values
    });
```

Comment: i don't understand what do you mean "rewrite with *callbacks*"?

Comment: Your question is wordy and not very clear. Where do callbacks come in? If you're trying to save a state without variables, you could just add a property to the object. `$('.svg-position').attr('data-prev-state', $('.svg-position').attr("transform"));`

Comment: Naive Approach is fin with different labels. Nothing wrong with it unless you wanna make it more DRY. Is that what you want?

Comment: @AMIR If we look at the first 2 lines *x* & *y* are assigned a value and the desire is to have those values passed to the third line but that is not what happens. Instead, the third line assigns the very last values assigned to  *x* & *y*. I thought using a *callback* is how to avoid this, perhaps I am wrong.

Comment: @ShyamBabu Nothing wrong I know, I would just like to know how to write this with out needing to use new labels, to make it more DRY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.svg-icon').click(function () {
    const getXY = (xid, yid)=> ({x: $(xid).slider("value"), y: $(yid).slider("value")})
    const setXY = (elId,{x, y})=>$(elid).attr("x", x).attr("y" ,y);
    const getScale = (elId) => $(elid).slider("value");

    const {x,y} = getxy('.slider-x','.slider-y')
    $('.svg-position').attr("transform", "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")");


    setXY('.strapline-text', getXY('.slider-strapline-text-x', ".slider-title-text-y"))
    setXY('.title-text', getXY('.slider-title-text-x', '.slider-title-text-y'))


    $('.svg-size').attr("transform", "scale(" + getScale('.slider-svglogo-scale') / 100 + ")");
    $('.svg-business-title').css("font-size", getScale('.slider-title-text-scale') + "px");
    $('.svg-strap-line').css("font-size", getScale("slider-strapline-text-scale") + "px"); 


    var strap = $('.text-strap').val();
    $('.svg-strap-line').text(strap);
    //some code that builds html and sets values
});
```

You could make it more DRY with Jquery expertise but then the code would become unreadable in my opinion. Still no more labels.